# how do i low-security encode a single column within a large mysql table, and then reverse it?

Tags: mysql, string, encode

How do I turn DATA into DATAENCODED... and then, when I need to later, programmatically reverse DATAENCODED back into DATA?

This is a file with 10K rows, so it has to be programmatic. Also, this is just meant to be "inconvenience" level security, so the simpler, the better.

Thanks!

```
    +-------+-------------+---------------+----------+
    |  key  |      data   |dataencoded    | otherdata|
    +-------+-------------+---------------+----------+
    |    1  | fred        |               | apple    |
    |       |         +----->             |          |
    +-------+-------------+---------------+----------+
    |    2  | hat     +------>            |pear      |
    +-------+-------------+---------------+----------+
    |    3  | cat      +---->             |orange    |
    +-------+-------------+---------------+----------+
    |    4  | hat      +---->             |grape     |
    +-------+-------------+--------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Encode or encrypt? Encoding is hardly an 'inconvenience' from a security point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't get simpler than this:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET dataencoded = ENCODE(data, 'password') WHERE ...
```

Or if you want somewhat stronger encryption:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET dataencoded = AES_ENCRYPT(data, 'password') WHERE ...
```

Well okay, it can be simpler if you just want to obscure the data, not use a password:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET dataencoded = HEX(data) WHERE ...
```

See [`ENCODE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_encrypt), [`AES_ENCRYPT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt), or [`HEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_hex).

Comment: Thanks! Assuming I use UPDATE MyTable SET dataencoded = HEX(data) WHERE ..how do I reverse this later, and get the original DATA?

Answer (score 0):

Choose a mysql crypt function from [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html).